# How to find element if part of selector is dynamic through WebdriverIO + Appium?

Tags: javascript, automation, appium, webdriver-io

I'm working on mobile automation project (Using webdriverio, appium and
appium-youiengine-driver https://github.com/YOU-i-Labs/appium-youiengine-driver )

I need a find an element, which selector (rntestid) one part is dynamic, other part is static.
Selector each time looks differently
Some this selector examples

```
1. BadgeTimer_56ab5c05-a3ct-8500-1f79
2. BadgeTimer_66ef0s25-e2bf-1234-1a76
3. BadgeTimer_12nj5i15-g4oy-0002-4f90
4. BadgeTimer_13eb5k78-u8qw-3480-2b49
5. BadgeTimer_90fb5v75-e2bf-7560-1k59
```

Always **BadgeTimer_** is visible, but other part of selector is dynamic. How I can define it?

Comment: Use Contains in xpath.  resource-id is attribute name.

//*[contains(@resource-id,"BadgeTimer_")]
   (or)   
//*[starts_with(@resource-id,"BadgeTimer_")]